# Comparing multiple lines of strings in a variable

Tags: python, string

How to check whether a para is present in a file or not using python.

For example, sampleData is 
    `backtick escapes like _so_
    quote by placing > at start of line
    to make links
    <http://foo.com>
    [foo](http://foo.com)
    <a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>`

and i want to search for
`quote by placing > at start of line
    to make links
    <http://foo.com>`

I tried normal search functions like sampledata.find('quote by placing > at start of line
    to make links
    http://foo.com') which didnot work actually.

Comment: What's the value of sampledata?

Comment: When you tried `para in sampledata` what errors or problems did you have?

Comment: str.find() should work. You can print data with repr() to check out the differece between search pattern and `sampledata`, such as, newlines.

Comment: @Dogbert edited the question .,., small correction is  there is a newline after  </p> tag and 5 white spaces before the <span> tag.,.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator and any search functions work no matter the value:

```
>>> needle = '`Searching > for text`'
>>> haystack = 'You are `Searching > for text`, are you not?'
>>> needle in haystack
True
```

If you want more advanced matching (like skip certain characters, and allow arbitrary whitespace in between), use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: in is returning false. i gave another example in the question.,,. 
there is a newline after </p> tag and 5 white spaces before the <span> tag

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data:

```
>>> '<strong><u></u></strong></p> <span class="info">'.find('</p> <span class="info">')
24
```

Comment: there is a newline after </p> tag and 5 white spaces before the <span> tag .,, its not appearing here. To be more clear the sampledata is
`<strong><u></u></strong></p>`
      `<span class="info">`